# How to get rid of trailing comma and space in the end of the stringBuilder?

Tags: java, java-stream, stringbuilder

I added a comma when it is missing in the string and want to get rid of the comma from the end of the string and trim additional space from the new line in the end.

```
StringBuilder mssg = new StringBuilder();

if (hasError().size <=8){
hasError().keySet().stream().forEach(id ->{
mssg.append(id.toString() + ":");
hasError().get(id).stream.limit(8).forEach(error ->mssg.append(error.toString() + ", "))
mssg.append("\n"); // adding new line for each Id to show it's own error mssg
)}


error output: Missing xnameMissing ynameMissing xyzMissing abcMissing ab, cd or ef,
Id: Id1
```

so with my code - I am adding comma separating the error output to the string so the output of mssg would be

mssg output: Id1: Missing xname, Missing yname, Missing xyz, Missing abc, Missing ab, cd, or ef,

there is multiple missing error output for 1 item

```
Id1:Missing xname, Missing yname, Missing xyz, Missing abc, Missing ab, cd, or ef,
Id2:Missing yname, Missing ab, cd, or ef,
Id3:Missing xyz,
new line
```

Comment: `msg.append(hasError().get(id).stream.limit(8).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));`

Comment: Elliott Frisch - I cannot do that otherwise I wouldn't be able to access the error Output which I am getting for each Id.

Comment: `msg.append(hasError().get(id).stream.limit(8).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to remove the last 2 characters from a `StringBuilder`:

```
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
```

To cater for the case where the original list could be empty:

```
sb.setLength(Math.max(0, sb.length() - 2));
```

But I think a better solution would be to not put the misplaced separator there in the first place; e.g. build the string like this:

```
stream.limit(8).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why you couldn't do this.

```java
      StringBuilder mssg = new StringBuilder();
      Map<String, List<Integer>> hasError =
            Map.of("A", List.of(1, 2, 3, 4), "B", List.of(10, 20, 30, 4));

      if (hasError.size() <= 8) {

         hasError.keySet().stream().forEach(id ->
         {
            mssg.append(id + ":");

            mssg.append(
                  hasError.get(id).stream().limit(8).map(a -> a + "").collect(
                        Collectors.joining(", ")));

            mssg.append("\n");
         });
      }
      System.out.println(mssg);
   }
```

It prints.

> B:10, 20, 30, 4 
>    A:1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Even better would be streaming over `entrySet()` instead of streaming over the `keySet()` and performing a lookup for every key. Then, there’s no need for two statements or a manual use of `StringBuilder`: `String result = hasError.entrySet().stream() .map(e -> e.getValue().stream().limit(8) .map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", e.getKey() + ":", ""))) .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));`